# Problem With Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, huawei

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 14.04 2-3 days before. And I am facing the problem when I insert the Data Card (USB Internet Dongle), my laptop stops working, even mouse pointer doesn't move, touch also doesn't work. I then reinstalled ubuntu. And still I am facing the same problem

Laptop Specs
Acer Aspire V5
RAM : 6 GB
HDD: 1 TB

USB Dongle
Huawei E303

Comment: Is that for any USB or just this Internet Dongle?

Comment: So you're inserting a network dongle after computer has booted up. What about booting with the dongle plugged in? Also, what you can do is go to /var/log folder and copy a few logs, such as dmesg  and apport.log . Maybe they will give a clue as to what exactly is going on

Comment: @Vembu, there is this dongle only

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "when i insert  USB" and be specific on "doesn't work"

1. Do you insert USB first and then Power the laptop **or**
2. Do you Power uplaptop first then insert USB?

IF 1: check your BIOS at start up[powerup while pressing f11 or find suitable for your laptop] 
  THEN: set up boot-up drive properly

Comment: I tried the both. No difference